# Issue with to.weekly parameter drop.time

Tags: r, xts

I am either misunderstanding the docs or having a problem with the `drop.time=TRUE` parameter in `to.weekly()`. For a simple example, add a time component onto some sample daily data and roll it up to weekly:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
d <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
index(d) <- index(d)+50

w1 <- to.weekly(d, drop.time=TRUE)
head(w1,1)
                      d.Open   d.High    d.Low  d.Close
2007-01-07 00:00:50 50.03978 50.42188 49.95041 49.99185

w2 <- to.weekly(d, drop.time=FALSE)
head(w2,1)
                      d.Open   d.High    d.Low  d.Close
2007-01-07 00:00:50 50.03978 50.42188 49.95041 49.99185
```

The docs say:

> Setting `drop.time` to TRUE (the default) will convert a series that 
>   includes a time component into one with just a date index, as the 
>   time index is often of little value in lower frequency series.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757430/xts-error-order-by-requires-an-appropriate-time-based-object) mentions that `drop.time` depends upon `indexClass(d)[1] == 'POSIXt'` but that appears not to help:

```
indexClass(d)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

indexClass(d) <- c('POSIXt', 'POSIXct')
w3 <- to.weekly(d, drop.time=TRUE, name=NULL)
head(w3,1)
                        Open     High      Low    Close
2007-01-07 00:00:50 50.03978 50.42188 49.95041 49.99185
```

I'm sure I can just truncate off the time component, but am curious what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like it may be a bug in `xts:::.drop.time`.  I'm investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in r613 on [R-forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=118).  `xts:::.drop.time` was looking for the virtual `POSIXt` class in the first position of the class attribute, but (at some point) the order of the `POSIXct` and `POSIXt` classes had been switched in base R.  I tried to make this check more robust to future changes.

I also made `xts:::.drop.time` actually change the underlying index.  It had been setting `indexClass(x) <- "Date"`, but the underlying index was still the original `POSIXt` times (including intra-day components).  This would cause funky merges.

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
d1 <- d2 <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
index(d1) <- index(d1)+50
D1 <- to.daily(d1)
D2 <- to.daily(d2)
head(merge(D1,D2),2)  # old behavior
            d1.Open  d1.High   d1.Low d1.Close  d2.Open  d2.High   d2.Low d2.Close
2007-01-02       NA       NA       NA       NA 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
2007-01-02 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778       NA       NA       NA       NA
head(merge(D1,D2),1)  # new behavior
            d1.Open  d1.High   d1.Low d1.Close  d2.Open  d2.High   d2.Low d2.Close
2007-01-02 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
```

Thanks for the report and example!

Comment: Thanks for support and the great tools, Josh. Sorta sorry this turned out to be a bug report.

Comment: @khoxsey: don't be sorry. User feedback helps create better software.